# Determining the transpose of a CustomLinearOperator

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

Using `from scipy.sparse.linalg import LinearOperator` I want to determine the transpose of a `<3x3 _CustomLinearOperator with dtype=float64>>`. Consider the following random permutation of coordinate axes:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse.linalg import LinearOperator

n=3
x = np.arange(n)
np.random.shuffle(x)

def w(v): 
    n = len(v)
    w = np.zeros((n,1))
    for j in range(n):
        w[j] = v[x[j]]
    return np.array(w)

W = LinearOperator((n,n), matvec=w)
```

Note that `W` is an orthogonal matrix. `W.tranpose` leads to `<bound method LinearOperator.transpose of <3x3 _CustomLinearOperator with dtype=float64>>` but I don't know how to handle this `method`. What I would like to calculate is `W.tranpose*W` as `<3x3 _CustomLinearOperator with dtype=float64>>` but this of course is an `unsupported operand type`.

Comment: Look at the `LinearOperator` code.  `.transpose` delegates the action to `._transpose`, which is not defined in this abstract class.  While the underlying array has a `transpose`, this Operator class does not automatically use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the transpose of the operator yourself otherwise it won’t know what operation to apply; you cannot assume that scipy would know what is the transpose of the operator of it even exist.

You can read in the following link:
https://www.google.com/amp/s/samrelton.wordpress.com/2013/12/04/implicit-matrices-in-python/amp/

Side note: you are trying to calculate the norm so once you define the transpose you’ll able to apply norm like functions

Comment: Shouldn't ```rmatvec``` be used for defining it?

Comment: @Pazu you should define the appropriate transpose function, lets say `w_t(v)`, and then define the transpose operator like: `W.T = LinearOperator((n,n), matvec=w_t)`; then the operation `W.T*W` will be properly defined

Comment: and this is the only way?

Comment: @Pazu I’m not familiar with a different approach; but would be happy to learn if there is an alternative